# Existence of rational parametrization of elliptic curves

Tags: elliptic-curves

I read somewhere that it is not possible to have rational parametrization for elliptic curves. So there is possibility of the existence of rational parametrization for a 'part' of elliptic curve or which may just miss finite number of points on the curve?

Comment: In that case the function field of the curve would be $\cong \overline{K}(x)$ and its genus would be $0$.

Comment: To expand on @reuns, you can’t get a rational parametrization of even the slightest part of an elliptic curve, so long as that part isn’t finite, of course.

Comment: Got it. Thank you